# inversions in array

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

If the worst case arrays {5 4 3 2 1} have number of inversions as Θ(n^2) => n(n-1)/2 swaps
The best case arrays {1 2 3 4 5} have number of inversions 0(no swap)

What kind of arrays have number of inversions Θ(n)?

{2 1 3 4 5} can this be an array with number of inversions Θ(n) as there will be only 1 swap.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if to place the minimal element into the maximal position, you'll get $n-1$ inversions:

$${2,3,4,5,1}$$

For more information please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)).

Answer (score 1):

Number of permutations of length $n$ with $k$ inversions refers to so called [Mahonian numbers](https://oeis.org/A008302) $T(n,k)$ who are generated by coefficients from expansion
$$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (1 + x + ... + x^i)$$